# How do I spend my Bitcoins without waiting for Bitcoin-Qt to sync?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, synchronization

I purchased $50 from ExpressCoins and now it's transferred to the address, but I hadn't realized that to use your program, I have to download 20 gigs of information.  Is there a way to access my coins without doing that and transfer them to the market in order to spend them?  I can't use the address at another wallet that doesn't do that?

A clear step-by-step would be a godsend at this point, and looking for threads and faqs to read has just confused me with more vague answers and piling on new programs and terms.

Comment: For future reference, please use the title to convey the gist of your question.

Answer (score 2):

If you use an iPhone, give [bread wallet](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/breadwallet-bitcoin-wallet/id885251393?mt=8) a try, the [Blockchain](http://blockchain.com/) app is cool, too. On Android I'd probably use [mycelium](https://mycelium.com/products).

All of those have nice and clean interfaces. Send some coins back and forth to get a feeling for it.

It's better for the network to run a full node (=use a client that downloads the whole 20Gig blockchain) but you don't necessarily need to, to send and receive BTC. All the apps I mentioned before dont require you to download the blockchain.

Technically Blockchain (the company) is an online wallet, which means they hold and secure your private keys (= the keys that allow sending money) while with bread wallet and mycelium you hold the private keys.

Blockchain = the company

the blockchain = the public ledger of Bitcoin

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly use [Blockchain.info](http://Blockchain.info) or 
[GreenAddress.it](http://GreenAddress.it) to avoid running a full node. Blockchain.info has FAQs but [WeUseCoins.com](http://WeUseCoins.com), [Bitcoin Wiki](http://bitcoin.it) or [Bitcoin.org](http://bitcoin.org) all have excellent FAQs.

If you've sent your Bitcoin to the address associated with the core program (ie the software you're waiting for to download the Blockchain, aka Bitcoin-QT) it's more complicated to spend your BTC until it's synced.

Communities like [BitcoinTalk.org](http://BitcoinTalk.org) and [/r/Bitcoin](http://reddit.com/r/bitcoin) are not always helpful with these basic questions so check the FAQs and you'll have a better idea.